Constructing a proposition in propositional logic which is a tautology if and only if ...
I'm trying to solve the following question:
Let $A=\left \{ a_1,..,a_n \right \}$ be a finite set of arbitrary elements and $B_1,...,B_m$ subsets of A.
Let $k\leq m$ be a natural number.
Write a proposition $\gamma$ in propositional logic, such that $\gamma$ is a tautology if and only if there exist $k$ $B_i$ sets, such that their union is equal to $A$.

What I done so far
Variables: For every $i\in[1,...n]$ , define a variable $p_i$.
Construct $A$ :
$A=\wedge_{i=1}^{n}\ p_i$
Construct $B$ :
$B=\vee_{i=1}^{m}\left ( \wedge_{p_i\in A}\ \ p_i\right )$
Finally:
$\gamma=\vee_{j=1}^{k}B_j= \vee_{j=1}^{k}\left ( \wedge_{p_i \in A} \ p_i\right ):\forall j_{1\leq j\leq k} \ , B_j\in B$
I'm failing to rigorously prove why this attempt is right (or wrong).

You need to provide more context. Propositional logic can't talk directly about membership of sets. You (probably) need to define propositional variables that represent the set-theoretic concepts: I would recommend defining variables $\beta_{ij}$ to mean that $a_i \in B_j$. But we need to see some more about how your course or textbook expects you to approach this kind of problem. I'll write a conjectural answer.

Tautologies aren't conditionally true. I think what you are being asked for is how to represent the property of interest in terms of primitive propositions that represent the relevant set-theoretic assertions. To do this, let's introduce propositional variables $\beta_{ij}$ for $1 \le i \le n$ and $1 \le j \le m$. $\beta_{ij}$ is intended to mean that $a_i \in B_j$ (those are all the membership statements we need to formulate what we have to say).
Now if $J = \{j_1, \ldots, j_k\} \subseteq [1, \ldots, m]$ and $1 \le i \le n$, $a_i \in B_{j_1} \cup \ldots B_{j_k}$ iff the following proposition holds:
$$\alpha_{iJ} \equiv \beta_{ij_1} \lor \ldots \lor \beta_{ij_k}$$.
So $A \subseteq B_{j_1} \cup \ldots B_{j_k}$ iff the following proposition holds:
$$\gamma_J \equiv \alpha_{1J} \land \ldots \land \alpha_{nJ}$$
Finally $A$ is contained in the union of $k$ of the $B_i$ iff the following proposition holds:
$$\delta \equiv \bigvee_{\begin{array}{c} J \subseteq [1, \ldots, m]\\
|J| = k\end{array}}\gamma_J$$

The task is certainly ambiguous, but the wording suggests to me that $\gamma$ should depend on the given sets. I wonder whether "is satisfiable" was intended instead of "is a tautology", because then (in addition to a trivial solution like the answer I posted) there's a sort of natural solution using $m$ propositional variables (which translates the "there exist $k$" into the $\exists$ in the definition of satisfiability).

@Karl: let's see if the OP can throw some light on what is actually required.

The only thing I got is that a variable must contain "basic information" - as soon as the information of the variable can be broken down into questions, this is not a correct expression of the problem in propositional logic.
According to this, the answer @Karl gave isn't right,(yet it seems an answer that answer the question) but I really don't understand the "basic information" part. Is it possible to ask you to elaborate on this ?

I suspect they are looking for something more like my suggestion where the "basic information" represents the primitive set-theoretic statements that you need to express the conditions. But then as @Karl points out there are problems with the use of the term tautology. I'm afraid you're going to have to get your teacher to explain.

@RobArthan Thank you very much for the help !!

Clearly $\gamma$ must depend on the given sets in some way, and no constraints were provided on how it is derived from them. We can simply take
$$\gamma=
\begin{cases}
p\lor\lnot p&&\text{if there exist $k$ of the $B_i$ whose union is $A$}\\
p&&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
which is of course a tautology if and only if the condition is met.
